Здравсвуйте, помогите мне структурировать БЭМ блок:


Общий БЭМ блок main-block, подскажите как мне изменить классы для его правильного структурирования

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Приведи код текстом
